# Reading a ini (text) file in Python 3 and use the data to print strings on the screen independently from the text file encode format

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

in these days I asked a couple of questions related to string encode and file encode in Python but the real problem is harder then I supposed to be and now I have a clearer understanding of the problem.

Windows encoded text files in different formats depending by the language or the language group. So, I would be able to read a ini (text file) encoded in different formats because some keys contain strings that I need to display on forms and menues on the screen.
So I would like to write something (that has to work with any text file and encode format) similar to this code example:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import magic

def detect(iniFileName):
    return magic.Magic(mime_encoding=True).from_file(iniFileName)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

encoding = detect('config.ini')
ini = ConfigParser()
ini.read('config.ini', encoding)
title = ini.get('USERENTRY-FORM', 'TITLE')
'''
then title is passed to the tk form
'''
UserEntryForm.setTitle(title)
if _DEBUG == True:
   print("USERENTRY-FORM title=",title)
```

This is the new solution that seems to work better because recognizes better the encode format, AIniParser is a wrapper class arund ConfigParser.

```
from chardet import detect

def chardetPrint(filename):
    text = open(filename, 'rb').read()
    print(filename,": ",detect(text))
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

def chardet(filename):
    text = open(filename, 'rb').read()
    print(filename,": ",detect(text)['encoding'])   # only for test
    return detect(text)['encoding']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from ainiparser import AIniParser
    
    def testIniRead(filename, section, key):
        with open(filename, "rb") as f:
            line = f.readline()
            print("line 1: ", line)
            
        encode = chardet(filename)
        ini = AIniParser(filename, encoding=encode)
        ini._open()
        text = ini.getString(section, key)
        print(text)
        
        
    def main():
        testIniRead("../cdata/config-cro-16.ini", "CGUIINTF", "game-turn-text")
        testIniRead("../bat/output-lva-16/idata/config-lva-16.ini", "CGUIINTF", "game-turn-text")
        testIniRead("../idata/config-lva-16.ini", "CGUIINTF", "game-turn-text")
        testIniRead("../idata/domande.ini", "D2", "B")
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
    main()
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

This solution seems recognizes better how files are encoded but I am still testing it.

Comment: I do not know the encode in advance... remember that the user may edit the files and the resulting encoding varies in function of the language and Windows version.

Comment: For instance seems that Python 3 does not like utf-8 files saved using notepad and in general any file with a BOM. Passing utf-8-sig to encoding parameter does not solve the problem and honestly I do not understand why.

Comment: The utf-8 BOM is not recommended, anyway it should be EF BB BF. Instead, a text file correctly encoded (these are the 1st 16 bytes):

EF BB BF 5B 44 31 5D 0D 0A 44 3D 20 49 6C 20 66

is not recognized as utf-8-sig and produces this exception/error:

file: '../idata/domande.ini', line: 1
'\ufeff[D1]\n'

so it is as the BOM is FE FF

so I suspect Python 3 (in this case 3.8.6) has problems to handle it.

Comment: Exactly, it is not required but some Windos o.s. version programs as notepad writes also the BOM but passing utf-8-sig seems it is not aleays sufficient. I am also lost... the problem is that customers may change the ini file, one it is a long configuration file and another one a set of questions and the customer may decide in which language write/edit/change the text of the questions. So, depending the program he uses to handle the file, the file itself may be saved in different encodings. At the moment the main problem is with utf-8-sig format, another couple of bugs may born in my sw.

Comment: I am still not sure about the right solution but seems that now the situation is better. I edited the main post including the little test source code I wrote and works quite better, may be the end solution but I am still testing it.